# Add item to cart in Squareup Android

Tags: android, square-connect

I am using `Squareup` to order product for my `Android` app. I checkout some apis like how to get items and item details, orders etc.
Now, I want to know that how do I add multiple items in cart and then proceed for it to checkout.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to itemize your transaction with the Point of Sale api for Android, you should add information in the `note` field of your `ChargeRequest.Builder`. In general you just pass the amount you want to charge, not the specific items.